# Displaying Timezone abbreviation with Date.js

Tags: javascript, timezone, datejs

I have a script that reads the users timezone and displays a time according to users. How do I display the timezone abbreviation?

I have a gaming site, and on posts we write "We'll be playing live at 7:00". Users from around the world read our blog, and want to watch live. I have the following script that is supposed to read the users timezone, and displays the time according to where the user lives.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Localtime</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    We'll be playing live at <span class="localtime">7:00PM EDT</span>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
    <script
      var els = document.getElementsByClassName('localtime');
      for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++)
        els[i].innerHTML = 
          Date.parse(els[i].innerHTML).toLocaleString();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I display a user-specific timezone abbreviation beside the time, so users know that the time is based on their timezone?

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- [date.js has been abandoned](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info). You should probably avoid using it.
- Time zone abbreviations are ambiguous.  See [this list](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/).
- For example, if you output as "CST" - that could mean "Central Standard Time", "China Standard Time" or "Cuba Standard Time".
- As far as I am aware, there aren't any libraries that will give you the abbreviation of the local time zone.
- You can usually see some zone information with just `Date().toString()`, but it is highly dependent on the browser.  It may come out as an abbreviation, or as a localized full name or id of the time zone, or not at all.
- Perhaps you would be better just showing the offset.  That would be standardized at least.  You could do that with raw JavaScript or even easier with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).
- In the code you provided, there is no input date, so you're going to have a difficult time locking it in to a particular time zone.  You are assuming that "EDT" is something that can be recognized by the date parser in all browsers, and that's not true.
- The best approach would be to start with an exact moment (either as UTC or with an offset), then render that to the correct format.  For example, (with moment.js)

  ```
  var m = moment("2013-08-06T19:00:00-04:00"); // this is 7PM EDT
  var s = m.format("HH:mm ([UTC]ZZ)");  // example: "16:00 (UTC-0700)"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Updated version of the DateJS core code (and will be fixing open bugs in the future) available here:

https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/

However it sounds like you're just looking for DateJS's format or toString methods.

For example:

```
var tmp = Date.parse("2013-09-05T22:40:00Z");
var time = tmp.format("g:i A T");
```

this would leave time with the string "3:40 PM PDT"

This doesn't rely on internal browser issues as DateJS performs a lookup based on the offset for the date (which doesn't change per browser).

Answer (score 0):

bigeasy's [Timezone](https://github.com/bigeasy/timezone) seems to be a solution that gives you the time zone abbreviation, although as implied by @matt-johnson, abbreviations [are not standardized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Abbreviations).

Example of trying out Timezone with Node.js (followed the [walk-through](http://bigeasy.github.io/timezone/)):

```
$ npm install timezone
$ node
> tz = require('timezone');
[Function]
> us = tz(require("timezone/America"));
[Function]
> us(us("2013-12-11 03:00"), "America/Detroit", "%Z")
'EST'
> us(us("2013-12-11 03:00"), "America/Los_Angeles", "%Z")
'PST'
> us(us("2013-10-11 03:00"), "America/Los_Angeles", "%Z")
'PDT'
```

---

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) has an [entry point "hook" for time zone abbreviations](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/777), but as far as I know there is not a library that takes advantage of this yet.

Answer (score 0):

try moment timezone,
http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/abbr/

```
<script>
   moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").zoneAbbr();
</script>
```

Please note that include moment.js, moment-timezone.js and moment-timezone-data.js